# How to use relative paths to open files in source code in CMake generated solution

Tags: c++, path, cmake, resources

I am using CMake to generate one executable and several libraries. I have specified the output folder of the executable and all libraries to a common "bin" folder.

Using:

```
set_target_properties (${PROJ} 
   PROPERTIES
   ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_DIR}"
   ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${BIN_DIR}"
   RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_DIR}"
   RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${BIN_DIR}"
   LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_DIR}"
   LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${BIN_DIR}"
)
```

In one of the libraries, I am opening a resource file using a relative path. This path is relative to the "bin" folder `.//Resources//file.jpg` (as the Resources folder is IN the bin folder).

When I run the exe from the visual studio debugger, I see that it correctly runs the exe from the bin folder but when it tries to open file.jpg, it looks in the path relative to `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`. So, `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR/Resources/file.jpg`. So, I get a run-time error saying file not found.

What is the best way to get around this? I don't want to copy all the resources in the `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`. Seems like there should be better way.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You need to set the correct working directory for debugging in the Visual Studio project properties. It should be `$(TargetDir)` rather than the default `$(ProjectDir)`.

Comment: Thanks Dan. That did the trick. The next question I had would have been how to set this in cmake so that you don't have to set it via VS. But apparently, there's no easy way to do this and it has to be done by modifying the .user file. You can post your response as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you need to set the correct working directory for debugging in the Visual Studio project properties. It should be `$(TargetDir)` rather than the default `$(ProjectDir)`.

[image: Properties Dialog]

---

To avoid having to manually modify the settings every time you generate a clean solution, you can use [`CONFIGURE_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/configure_file.html) to pre-generate a default *.user* file.

For example, I use the following template for my VS 2013 projects that sets:

- default command line arguments to use when running the app in debugger
- the working directory to use (all the configurations share one)
- adjusting the `PATH` to include the directory with all the pre-built dependencies and symbols

File `${ROOT}/build/template/executable_vs12.vcxproj.user`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>-D20</LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
    <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>$(TargetDir)\..\..\common\</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(SolutionDir)..\deps\bin;$(Path)
$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>-D20</LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
    <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>$(TargetDir)\..\..\common\</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(SolutionDir)..\deps\bin;$(Path)
$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|Win32'">
    <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>-D20</LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
    <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>$(TargetDir)\..\..\common\</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(SolutionDir)..\deps\bin;$(Path)
$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|Win32'">
    <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>-D20</LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
    <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>$(TargetDir)\..\..\common\</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(SolutionDir)..\deps\bin;$(Path)
$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>-D20</LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
    <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>$(TargetDir)\..\..\common\</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(SolutionDir)..\deps\bin;$(Path)
$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>-D20</LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
    <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>$(TargetDir)\..\..\common\</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(SolutionDir)..\deps\bin;$(Path)
$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|x64'">
    <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>-D20</LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
    <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>$(TargetDir)\..\..\common\</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(SolutionDir)..\deps\bin;$(Path)
$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|x64'">
    <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>-D20</LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
    <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>$(TargetDir)\..\..\common\</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(SolutionDir)..\deps\bin;$(Path)
$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

---

Next, I have a simple *.cmake* file that can be included and wraps the configure step.

File `${ROOT}/build/debugger_config.cmake`

```
IF(NOT COMMON_BUILD_DEBUGGER_CONFIG_INCLUDED)
SET(COMMON_BUILD_DEBUGGER_CONFIG_INCLUDED TRUE)
# =============================================================================
FUNCTION(CONFIGURE_DEBUGGER TARGET_NAME)
  CONFIGURE_FILE(${ROOT}/build/template/executable_vs12.vcxproj.user
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.vcxproj.user
    @ONLY
    )
ENDFUNCTION(CONFIGURE_DEBUGGER)
# =============================================================================
ENDIF(NOT COMMON_BUILD_DEBUGGER_CONFIG_INCLUDED)
```

Finally, I invoke this function after every executable target definition:

```
# This can go in top-level CMakeLists.txt
INCLUDE(${ROOT}/build/debugger_config.cmake)

# ...

ADD_EXECUTABLE(foo
  ${FOO_FILES}
)
CONFIGURE_DEBUGGER(foo)
```